# Sort result by taxonomy term weight

Tags: 7

```
 $query = db_select('node', 'n');
   $query->join('field_data_taxonomy_catalog', 'tc', 'n.nid = tc.entity_id');
   $query->leftjoin('field_data_field_chip', 'fdc', 'n.nid = fdc.entity_id');


   $query->fields('tc',array('taxonomy_catalog_tid'));
   $query->fields('fdc',array('field_chip_tid'));   

   $query->fields('n',array('nid'));

   $query->condition('tc.taxonomy_catalog_tid',$get_tid,'=');


   $query->orderby("fdc.field_chip_tid","ASC"); //I Want to sort the resultset on the basis of weight instead of the term Id. 


   $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll()
```

I need to sort the result on field_data_field_chip weight instead of the term Id. I am new to Drupal and don't know how to fetch the weight of the taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 2):

The `weight` column in the `taxonomy_term_data` table contains the information you need.

You can join it in to your current query via `taxonomy_term_data.tid`.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this from a sitebuilding perspective using Views:

1. You can use the module [Views Term Hierarchy Weight Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field), which not only sorts by weight but respects nesting of terms.
2. Alternatively, if your taxonomy does not have a hierarchy/nesting of terms [aka is flat], you can build a view with a relationship for the "Taxonomy Terms on Node".  Refer to this [Drupal issues post that walks you through how to set it u](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1355964)p.

Answer (score -3):

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/ordering

See drupal standard documentations, it may help you